# Python, getting exception args from sys info

Tags: python, exception

if I only have access to sys.exc_info(),

`exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()`

when this exception was raised,

```
class TestException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, arg_a):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.arg_a = arg_a
```

Is it possible to get access to the instance variable `arg_a` from either of, `exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback`?

Comment: `except TestException as e` and then just do `e.arg_a`? Or I guess that's out of your scope since you said you can only access it through `sys.exc_info`? But if so, why? That feels like a hack the box assignment or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's quite straight-forward:

```
import sys

class TestException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, arg_a):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.arg_a = arg_a

try:
    raise TestException("message", "spanish inquisition")
except TestException as e:
    print(e.arg_a)  # spanish inquisition
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print(exc_value.arg_a)  # spanish inquisition
```